# How to configure Terraform + Heroku + PointDNS

Tags: heroku, terraform, pointdns

I'm experimenting with Heroku + Terraform for my deployments but I can't figure out how to configure pointdns as a "heroku_addon" to use a specific domain (or the domain specified in "heroku_domain"). Below is my terraform config. Any ideas?

```
variable "heroku_app_name" {
  description = "Name of the Heroku app provisioned as an example"
  default     = "myapp"
}
terraform {
  required_providers {
    heroku = {
      source  = "heroku/heroku"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

# Build code & release to the app
resource "heroku_build" "this" {
  app_id     = heroku_app.this.id
  buildpacks = ["https://github.com/dokku/buildpack-nginx.git"]

  source {
    url     = "https://github.com/<account>/<repo>/tarball/<branch>"
    version = "latest"
  }
}
# Launch the app's web process by scaling-up
resource "heroku_formation" "this" {
  app_id     = heroku_app.this.id
  type       = "web"
  quantity   = 1
  size       = "basic"
  depends_on = [heroku_build.this]
}

# Associate a custom domain
resource "heroku_domain" "this" {
  app_id   = heroku_app.this.id
  hostname = "www.mydomain.com"
}


# Create a new Heroku app
resource "heroku_app" "this" {
  name   = var.heroku_app_name
  region = "us"
  acm    = true
}


# Add-on SSL to application
resource "heroku_addon" "pointdns" {
  app_id = heroku_app.this.id
  plan   = "pointdns:developer"
  config = {
    cname_target = heroku_domain.this.cname
  }

  depends_on = [heroku_domain.this]
}
```

I've tried various combinations of `resource "heroku_addon" "pointdns" {}` and `resource "heroku_addon_attachment" "pointdns" {}` but neither of those work as expected. I'm pretty sure I need to configure the domain name from within the heroku addon so that it shows up in the pointdns console (shown below)
[image]